# Configure SonarQube Cross Project Duplication for Multiple C# Projects with Shared Files

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We have SonarQube v5.1.2 currently configured with multiple C# SonarQube projects.  Each of the SonarQube projects is related to a separate .NET solution.  These solutions can have .NET projects that are shared between them.

When the "Cross project" setting is set to "True" for duplications, we noticed that files shared across SonarQube projects are being reported as duplicate.  Is this by design?  Is there any way to have it not report shared files as duplicate?

Thanks for the help.